# Help on $\left (\sum_{i=1}^m i \right)^p - \left (\sum_{i=1}^m i \right)^{p-1} \equiv 0 \mod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to solve for $p$ the above congruence. My try:

**Note:** $p$ is prime, all congruences are taken modulo $p$ and let $$a = \sum_{i=1}^m i$$.

$a^p - a^{p-1} \equiv 0 \implies a^{p-1}(a-1) \equiv 0$

So either $a^{p-1} \equiv 0$ or $a-1 \equiv 0$

On both cases it does not always work, but it **seems** that when $a-1 \not\equiv 0$, $a^{p-1} \equiv 0$

I don't know how to continue and even if it's true or false, but I know from testing that $p=3$ works. I would like answers without using the [Faulhaber formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) if possible.

Comment: If $p$ is odd, $a=m(m+1)/2$ is zero modulo $p$ if $p$ iff $m\equiv 0,-1\pmod p.$ $a\equiv 1\pmod p$ if  $p\mid m^2+m-2=(m+2)(m-1),$ iff $m\equiv -1,2\pmod p.$

Comment: If $p=2,$ it is always true.

Comment: So given $m,$ you can choose any prime divisor $p$ of $m(m-1)(m+1)(m+2).$ The only prime divisors of for all $m$ are $p=2,3.$

Comment: Note $a^{p-1}\equiv 0$ iff $a\equiv 0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry but I did not understood fully, can you explain it more? What is the first step on both assumptions at the first comment and how does that implies comment 3? I'm a lay at modular arithmetic so be patient please. I need to prove for all $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if $p=2$, then you get $a^2-a\equiv 0$ which is in fact always true no matter what $m$ is. So, $p=2$ is one solution. Let us find other $p$. We may assume $p$ is odd since we no longer need to find $p=2$.

Note that $a$ is the sum $1+2+...+m$, which is equal to $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$. As you have seen, $p$ must divide $a^{p-1}$ or $p$ must divide $a-1$.

If $p$ divides $a^{p-1}$, then $p$ must divide $a$ (because $p$ is prime). In other words, $p$ divide $m(m+1)/2$, and so $p$ divide $m(m+1)$. This implies that $p$ divides $m$ or $p$ divides $m+1$.

If $p$ divides $a-1$, then $p$ must divide $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}-1=\frac{m^2+m-2}{2}=\frac{(m+2)(m-1)}{2}$. Hence, $p$ divides $(m-1)(m+2)$. In other words, $p$ divides $m-1$ or $p$ divides $m+2$.

Combining everything together, this means that for any $m$, the prime $p$ that satisfies the congruence is any prime divisor of $m-1$, $m$, $m+1$, or $m+2$.

*Remark*: If the question asks for "For any $m$, find all prime $p$ that satisfy the congruence", then the answer is enough. However, if it is actually something like "Find all prime $p$ such that for any $m$, the congruence is satisfied", then the answer is not enough. The first type of question starts with a given $m$, and we must find $p$ which likely will depend on $m$. The second type of question asks us to find $p$ that must satisfy the congruence for any $m$ (so for example, if the $p$ only satisfies the congruence when $m=2$ but when $m=3$ the $p$ does not satisfy it, then that $p$ is not a solution).

If what you are looking for is the question of second type, then let us continue.

So our $p$ must satisfy the congruence, no matter what $m$ is. We know $p=2$ works as we have observed.

What about $p=3$? We have shown that $p$ must divide at least one of these numbers: $m-1,m,m+1,m+2$. However, these are four consecutive numbers. Hence, one of them is guaranteed to be a multiple of $3$, and so that number is of course divisible by $p=3$. So, $p=3$ also works!

What about $p\geq 5$ ? Such $p$ cannot actually be a solution, since if it is, then as we have seen, it must divide either one of $m-1,m,m+1,m+2$ for any choice of $m$. In particular, if we choose $m=p+2$, then our $p$ must divide either one of $p+1,p+2,p+3,p+4$. However, this is impossible for $p\geq 5$ as it cannot divide any of those (the only $p$ that can is $p=2$ or $3$). Thus, the only solutions to the congruence is $p=2$ or $p=3$.